# Sufficient statistic and independence of parameter

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, sufficient-statistics

What i know about sufficient statistics is that the conditional distribution of sample obtained given for particular statistic must be independent of parameter.. but how does this relate to the containing all information regarding parameter in sample.....
Elaborate plz .and is sufficient statistic unique

Comment: With regard to your second question: sufficient statistics are most certainly non-unique. Any linear transformation of sufficient statistics is also sufficient. Can you tell why?

Comment: Suppose t is sufficient  for p that is f(x/p)=g(t/p)h(x)..now consider a function y=u(t) that is u^-1(y) =t   now f(x/p)=g(u^-1(y)/p)h(x)..let g(u^-1(y)/p)=z(y/p)..thus y is such that f(x/p)=z(y/p)h(x)..hence y=u(t) is also sufficient

Answer (score 2):

Given some data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, the likelihood $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n;\theta)$ describes how "likely" different parameter values are. This is because the data are no longer random: we have one data set, and it does not change. This likelihood is a function of/in $\theta$. You plug in $\theta$, out comes a likelihood. The fact that this density changes when you plug in different values for the parameters, $\theta$, that tells you this data has "information" about the parameter $\theta$. I am  using the word "information" loosely here, but **Fisher Information**, for instance, tries to take quantify this same idea: how much the density changes for changing values of $\theta$.

Now looking at the conditional distribution of the data **given a sufficient statistic**, call it $T$, what happens? By definition, $T$ is sufficient when $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n|T=t)$ is free of $\theta$. If you think of it as a function of $\theta$, there is no $\theta$ when you write it out. You can also think of it as if you plot this function with $\theta$ on the x-axis, and $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n|T=t)$ on the y-axis of a plot (if $\theta$ is 1-d or if you make a plot for each component of $\theta$): in this case this will be a flat line.

What happened going from $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n;\theta)$ to $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n|T=t)$? We lost all of the "information" about $\theta$. How did we lose it? Well we conditioned on $T$. So this is why people say $T$ has all the information about $\theta$.

And yes, they are not unique. JohnK is correct.